# Pandas index using integer for data slicing

Tags: python, pandas

```
data=pd.Series(['a','b','c'],index=[1,3,5])
```

then when I used `data[1]`, I got key related value which is `'a'`

when I use `data[1:3]` then I got `'b'` and `'c'` which `1:3` here should refer to `0-2` default index for my understanding not `[1,3,5]` I have specified .

But when I create data like this

```
data=pd.Series(['a','b','c'],index=['1','3','5'])
```

then `data['3':'5']` then I have got `'b'` and `'c'`

Why when I use the integer as the index for data slicing I got different results as string as the index?

Comment: I think here is best use `iloc` like `print (data.iloc[1:3])` - it working same in both Series. If want select by indices use `print (data.loc[1:3])` and  `print (data.loc['1':'3'])`

Answer (score 0):

When you used this line, you set the actual indexes to 1,3,5:

```
data=pd.Series(['a','b','c'],index=[1,3,5])
```

I'm not sure why it is that you wanted to set the indexes to those numbers, unless they represent something important. You're probably looking to do this:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

If you print out your dataframe after that, you should expect to see what you're looking for.